# Hey, what's with the help pages?

Tags: bug

https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions:

> #### Why and how are some questions deleted?
>
> - Analysing user biorhythm..
> - Merging with Russian botnet..

https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask:

> #### How do I ask a good question?
>
> I have two XmlDocuments and I would like to move an XmlNode selected from one of the documents and append it at a particular location in the other document.
>
> The naively intuitive approach of simply calling AppendNode(xmlNodeFromDocument1) at the appropriate place of document 2, of course doesn't work because the method does not take care of manipulating the owning document.
>
> I finally found the answer literally as I was writing up this question, but since it took so long for us to find it in the System.Xml classes, I figured I'd post it here to assist anyone else stuck searching for it.

Is it a bug? Joke? Break-in?

Comment: Is it **really** so hard to look at the list of recent questions to see if this has already been asked?

Comment: @Oded, sorry, I looked and not found. Maybe I just typed this longer than 4 minutes.

Comment: @Oded That's a bit unnecessarily rude, given that the time difference between this post and the dupe target is less than 3 minutes. Presumably both bug reports were being written simultaneously; the only reason this one is a dupe is FGitW. You're expecting Sasha to have seen into the future before starting to write this question.

Comment: @randal'thor  this is the second dupe. I get that people are in a hurry to post any issue, but sometimes... a bit of patience is a blessing.

Comment: The dupe posters are the ones who had patience :-) The most impatient-to-post user is the one who got in there first with the dupe *target*.

Comment: Apologies to @Sasha - Friday night, a bit of alcohol and too many duplicates just got to me.

Comment: I can't see any bug. Did you fixed it already??  I missed it.

Comment: @SagarV, yes, it's fixed.

Comment: Ya. I missed it. Screenshots available shows it is really fun. My bad